# How to click on XPath using iMacro

Tags: javascript, html, xpath, imacros, browser-automation

These are the steps that I want to do using iMacro (chrome plugin):

From the Instagram profile example https://www.instagram.com/username/ the iMacro will click on only the first photo & photo will popup then this photo will liked by iMacro.

```
TAG XPATH="//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/a" CONTENT=demo123 
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Like
TAB T=1
```

the problem is that iMacro can't find the URL of the first post or says that it's not able to click on the 1st photo. If I mentally click on 1st photo then iMacro will automatically like that photo means 2nd function is working perfect, but there is problem with 1st step.

I think my XPath is wrong or may be problem is iMacro syntax.

- this is for heart:

  ```
  //*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/a
  ```
- this is for post link:

  ```
  //*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/a
  ```

I also have tried this

```
TAG POS=5 TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:"_rxftm _8scx2 coreSpriteHeartSmall
```

Please, someone help me to solve this problem.
[Here is the Documentation](http://wiki.imacros.net/XPATH).

Comment: I have reformatted your whole question. Please check if I had done something wrong (and fix it if necessary).

Answer (score 0):

Try this XPath:

```
TAG XPATH="//*[@id='react-root']/section/main/article/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/a/div[1]"
```

or this selector:

```
TAG SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>SPAN>SECTION>MAIN>ARTICLE>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>A>DIV:nth-of-type(1)"
```

Comment: I have try the both  but nothing is happend                                                                                                  TAG SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>SPAN>SECTION>MAIN>ARTICLE>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>A>DIV:nth-of-type(1)"
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Like                                                                   
TAB T=1

Comment: Have you tried to record the click in **Conventional recording mode** with **Use CSS selectors** checked? What's happened when you replay this macro?